# Build asynchronous complex render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am building a very complex `React` `Component` with lots of `data`/`divs` inside.
You can simulate a heavy `render` method like this:

```
export default function ComplexComponent(props) {
  return [...Array(9999).keys()].map(() => <div />);
}
```

Since the `render`/`return` is blocking, the Page load is pretty slow. Is there a pattern, that allows me to `asynchronously` `render` the Page and show some `Spinner` while constructing the `Component`?
For now I only got some asynchronously data fetching examples which is not the problem in this case.

Comment: Why would an async function help here?

Comment: The user does not have to wait seconds to see the whole page because the `render` method does not block the whole rendering process.

Comment: Async won't stop the render being blocked here. The reason async works for network requests is because the fetching is done on a different thread.

Comment: One pattern is chunking, only render a couple elements, then, after some delay or on scroll, render another chunk of elements. To avoid a slow page, think about trashing components that are no longer useful to the user (out of sight, etc).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React non-blocking rendering of big chunks of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193867/react-non-blocking-rendering-of-big-chunks-of-data)

Comment: Pagination/Infinite scroll is probably one part of the solutions but not exactly that I was looking for, since there are many `divs` on the viewable page space.

Comment: @tomole then don't use scroll, just use something like `setTimeout` or a promises chain to trigger the next chunk render.

Comment: Though, that many elements are likely going to slow down the whole page (depending on the end-user gear) even after being asynchronously rendered, so I'd look into simplifying the whole thing to only render what's absolutely necessary, or rethink the design to split the complexity into some contextual modals or sub-pages.